# Probability of a point from (generalized) Student's T will be greater than point from another (generalized) Student's T?

Tags: probability

Consider the Generalized Student's T distribution, $T(\mu,\sigma^2,\nu)$.

Suppose $X_1 \sim T(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2,\nu_1)$ and $X_2 \sim T(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2,\nu_2)$, with $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent. What is $P(X_1 > X_2) = P(X_1 - X_2 > 0)$? Clearly, $E[X_1+X_2] = \mu_1+\mu_2$, but the rest isn't so clear.

Is there easily computable solution similar to: [Probability of a point taken from a certain normal distribution will be greater than a point taken from another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/probability-of-a-point-taken-from-a-certain-normal-distribution-will-be-greater)

Comment: I don't think so. The proof that 2 normal distributions add up to a normal distribution is actually quite involved.